# Config Multiple IP config in squid proxy server

Tags: proxy, squid

This answer seem not fit my requirement:
[Squid config - same user multiple ips](https://serverfault.com/questions/114204/squid-config-same-user-multiple-ips)

Assume that I have a proxy server with 3 IPV4 (202.6.7.8-9-10) and 20 IPV6 (ipv6_1 -> ipv6_20)

I want to config to

Allow IP(s) 203.166.233.16-17-18 to connect to port 3000 to 3010 to use proxy ipv6_1 to ipv6_10

Allow IP(s) 203.166.233.20-21-22 to connect to port 4000 to 4010 to use proxy ipv6_11 to ipv6_20

username1/pwd1 to connect to port 1001-1002 outgoing with ipv4 202.6.7.9-10

username2/pwd2 to connect to port 1201-1202 outgoing with ipv4 202.6.7.9-10

[image]

I try below config but there are 2 problem:

1. There are 6 allowed ips but whole internet can access
2. Allowed ips can cross access other ports

```
    dns_v4_first off
    acl to_ipv6 dst ipv6
    http_access deny !to_ipv6
    http_access allow to_ipv6
    
    #gourp 1 (ipv6)
    acl group_1 src 203.166.233.16 203.166.233.17 203.166.233.18
    
    http_port 202.6.7.8:3001
    http_port 202.6.7.8:3002
    http_port 202.6.7.8:3003
    http_port 202.6.7.8:3004
    http_port 202.6.7.8:3005
    
    acl lip_3001 myport 3001
    acl lip_3002 myport 3002
    acl lip_3003 myport 3003
    acl lip_3004 myport 3004
    acl lip_3005 myport 3005
    
    tcp_outgoing_address a001:aaa:bbb::31 lip_3001
    tcp_outgoing_address a001:aaa:bbb::32 lip_3002
    tcp_outgoing_address a001:aaa:bbb::33 lip_3003
    tcp_outgoing_address a001:aaa:bbb::34 lip_3004
    tcp_outgoing_address a001:aaa:bbb::35 lip_3005
    
    http_access allow group_1
    http_access deny !group_1
    
    #gourp 2 (ipv6)
    acl group_2 src 203.166.233.20 203.166.233.21 203.166.233.22
    
    http_port 202.6.7.8:4001
    http_port 202.6.7.8:4002
    http_port 202.6.7.8:4003
    http_port 202.6.7.8:4004
    http_port 202.6.7.8:4005
    
    acl lip_4001 myport 4001
    acl lip_4002 myport 4002
    acl lip_4003 myport 4003
    acl lip_4004 myport 4004
    acl lip_4005 myport 4005
    
    tcp_outgoing_address a001:aaa:bbb::41 lip_4001
    tcp_outgoing_address a001:aaa:bbb::42 lip_4002
    tcp_outgoing_address a001:aaa:bbb::43 lip_4003
    tcp_outgoing_address a001:aaa:bbb::44 lip_4004
    tcp_outgoing_address a001:aaa:bbb::45 lip_4005
    
    http_access allow group_2
    http_access deny !group_2
    
    #Enable IPV4 Proxies
    dns_v4_first on
    acl to_ipv4 dst ipv4
    http_access allow to_ipv4
    
    #group 3 (ipv4 user/pwd auth)
    http_port 202.6.7.8:1001
    http_port 202.6.7.8:1002
    
    acl lip_1001 myport 1001
    acl lip_1001 myport 1001
    
    tcp_outgoing_address 202.6.7.9 lip_1001
    tcp_outgoing_address 202.6.7.10 lip_1002
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? The question you linked has enough information for you to start building your own solution.

Comment: @AlexD the topic I mentioned does not have ip based authentication per out going port range